# Can we have container app as React application and other microfront end apps in Nextjs using module federation?

Tags: webpack-5, webpack-module-federation

Can we have container app as React application and other microfront end apps in Nextjs using module federation? since i need to reuse some of the nextjs applications

Comment: Can you provide more details? How exactly do you want to reuse your apps, and why can't you do that right now?

Comment: i have some nextjs apps running in production, i need to resuse those apps in my classic react application, which acts as a container, i need to add those nextjs remote entry files to react app webpack config. is it possible?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.